# How to disable the Windows Button on a tablet?

Tags: windows-8

I need to set up a tablet that runs a WPF application in a sort of Kiosk Mode similar to that found with Metro GUI Apps.

The only problem that seems to be left is the Windows button on the front of the tablet. Is there some way I can disable it or uninstall drivers that makes it work so that a user can't press it to get out of the app?

It's a Lenovo Thinkpad 10.

Comment: Have you tried if this works, although it is a bit hack-y? Add a new REG_BINARY type entry "Scancode Map" to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\ and make its value "00000000000000000300000000005BE000005CE000000000" without quotations
To enable it again, delete the entry. It might also work by changing the value to zero or empty. This is from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216893

Comment: Alright, I will give that a try and report back. Thank you so far :)

Comment: @JuhaUntinen If you want to make it an answer, I'll mark it because that did the trick! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but it is a bit hack-y:

1. Add a new REG_BINARY type entry called `Scancode Map` to the registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\`
2. Make its value equal to `00000000000000000300000000005BE000005CE000000000`
3. To enable the button again, delete the entry. It might also work by changing the value to zero or empty.

This is from http://www.support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216893

Comment: And to apply the changes, you need to restart after you have added the entry :)